# Recurring error using renderMenu with R

Tags: r

I am currently learning to use R and more specifically Shinydashboards to create... well, dashboards. 
As I am a R beginner, I have been working through the shinydashboard tutorial (https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html), trying to reproduce it and adapt it to my needs. It all went well until the code part concerning dynamic content, and especially dynamic message menu. 
When I copied the tutorial's code for an interactive message menu and run the entire script, the shiny window popped up and closed immediately with an error message (see below for codes and message).
I then tried to look the internet for other examples of dynamic menus, but found few, and discovered that each time the function renderMenu is used, I have the same error message with a shiny window quickly popping and closing.

Here is the code I had up to the problematic part (all seems to work well, I get a shiny window with some descriptive and interactive content) :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="AQUILAIR PLUS",
              dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
                           messageItem(
                             from = "Sales Dept",
                             message = "Sales are steady this month."
                           ),
                           messageItem(
                             from = "New User",
                             message = "How do I register?",
                             icon = icon("question"),
                             time = "13:45"
                           ),
                           messageItem(
                             from = "Support",
                             message = "The new server is ready.",
                             icon = icon("life-ring"),
                             time = "2014-12-01"
                           )),
              dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
                                        notificationItem(
                                          text = "5 new users today",
                                          icon("users")
                                        ),
                                        notificationItem(
                                          text = "12 items delivered",
                                          icon("truck"),
                                          status = "success"
                                        ),
                                        notificationItem(
                                          text = "Server load at 86%",
                                          icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"),
                                          status = "warning"
                                        )
                           )             
              ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
)
),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              h2("Graphes de suivi"),
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "Graphiques", status = "primary", 
          plotOutput("plot1", height = 250),
          plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)
      ),

      box(title= "Informations", status = "info",
    "Texte descriptif", br(), "blablabla",
    sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50),
    sliderInput("slider2", "Curseur 2:", 1, 200, 25),
    textInput("text", "Commentaire :")
  ),
      box(title = "Commentaires éventuels", status="success",
      solidHeader = TRUE,
      collapsible = TRUE,
    "Commentaire :",
    textOutput("text")
      )  
    )
  ),
  # Second tab content
  tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
      h2("Widgets tab*** content")
  )
)
)
) 

server <- function(input, output) { 
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  output$text <- renderText({
    print(input$text)
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    data2 <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider2)]
    hist(data2)
  })

  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Then I tried to copy paste the tutorial to get a dynamic message menu :

in the ui part :

```
dashboardHeader(dropdownMenuOutput("messageMenu"))
```

in the server part :

```
output$messageMenu <- renderMenu({
  # Code to generate each of the messageItems here, in a list. This assumes
  # that messageData is a data frame with two columns, 'from' and 'message'.
  msgs <- apply(messageData, 1, function(row) {
    messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["message"]])
  })

  # This is equivalent to calling:
  #   dropdownMenu(type="messages", msgs[[1]], msgs[[2]], ...)
  dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
})
```

There comes the closing window with the following error message :

```
Warning: Error in markRenderFunction: unused argument (outputArgs =       outputArgs)
Stack trace (innermost first):
45: markRenderFunction
44: renderMenu
43: server [#15]
 4: <Anonymous>
 3: do.call
 2: print.shiny.appobj
 1: <Promise>
Error in markRenderFunction(uiOutput, renderFunc, outputArgs = outputArgs) : 
  unused argument (outputArgs = outputArgs)"
```

I first figured out that messageData was not defined, so I added at the beginning of the code :

```
 messageData = data.frame('from' = c('me', 'you', 'them'), 'message' = c('first message' ,'second','third'))
```

but it did not change the behaviour of the window nor the error message.
Here is my entire "errored code" :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
messageData = data.frame('from' = c('me', 'you', 'them'), 'message' = c('first message' ,'second','third'))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="AQUILAIR PLUS",
              dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
                           messageItem(
                             from = "Sales Dept",
                             message = "Sales are steady this month."
                           ),
                           messageItem(
                             from = "New User",
                             message = "How do I register?",
                             icon = icon("question"),
                             time = "13:45"
                           ),
                           messageItem(
                             from = "Support",
                             message = "The new server is ready.",
                             icon = icon("life-ring"),
                             time = "2014-12-01"
                           )),
              dropdownMenuOutput("messageMenu"),
              dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
                                        notificationItem(
                                          text = "5 new users today",
                                          icon("users")
                                        ),
                                        notificationItem(
                                          text = "12 items delivered",
                                          icon("truck"),
                                          status = "success"
                                        ),
                                        notificationItem(
                                          text = "Server load at 86%",
                                          icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"),
                                          status = "warning"
                                        )
                           )             
              ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
          h2("Graphes de suivi"),
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "Graphiques", status = "primary", 
      plotOutput("plot1", height = 250),
      plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)
      ),

      box(title= "Informations", status = "info",
        "Texte descriptif", br(), "blablabla",
        sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50),
        sliderInput("slider2", "Curseur 2:", 1, 200, 25),
        textInput("text", "Commentaire :")
      ),
      box(title = "Commentaires éventuels", status="success",
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          collapsible = TRUE,
        "Commentaire :",
        textOutput("text")
      )  
    )
  ),
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
          h2("Widgets tab*** content")
  )
)
)
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  output$text <- renderText({
    print(input$text)
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
   output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    data2 <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider2)]
    hist(data2)
  })
  output$messageMenu <- renderMenu({
    msgs <- apply(messageData, 1, function(row) {
      messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["message"]])

   })
dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs) 
  })
  }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Looking for other examples of dynamic menu, as I said, I found few things, many examples being exactly the same code, which is not helping... but I did found this one in the renderMenu help :

```
    # ========== Dynamic sidebarMenu ==========
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("menu")
  ),
  dashboardBody()
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$menu <- renderMenu({
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Menu item", icon = icon("calendar"))
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

...and it gives me the same exact window behaviour and error message, which means, I guess, that I have a serious problem with the renderMenu function.
I have tried to insert outputArgs in my code but while I get it must be a list, I don't really understand how and where it is to be used.

I apologize in advance if I missed something enormous; I know it can seem basic code to many, but I am a beginner and would really appreciate some help/explainations as I am stuck there with my non-dynamic menus :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think messageData should be in the form:

```
messageData = data.frame('from' = c('me', 'you'), 'message' = c('first message' ,'second'))
```

You could also check in your render code if message data is valid using something like below, which provide no input unless messageData is good.

```
  output$messageMenu <- renderMenu({
    req(messageData, cancelOutput = TRUE)
    msgs <- apply(messageData, 1, function(row) {
      messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["message"]])
    })
    dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)  
  })
```

I've jsut noticed, you have some misplaced brackets, that I corrected without telling you. In your last code block you have:

```
 output$messageMenu <- renderMenu({
    msgs <- apply(messageData, 1, function(row) {
      messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["message"]])
    dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)  # this should be outside the fucntion in the apply call.
   })
  })
  }
```

EDIT: Here is a full copy and paste of the code I'm running successfully. switch the comment on the first like to see how the req() code helps when messageData is invalid.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
messageData = data.frame("from" = c('me', 'you'), "message" = c('first message' ,'second'))
#messageData = NULL

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="AQUILAIR PLUS",
                  dropdownMenu(type = "messages",
                               messageItem(
                                 from = "Sales Dept",
                                 message = "Sales are steady this month."
                               ),
                               messageItem(
                                 from = "New User",
                                 message = "How do I register?",
                                 icon = icon("question"),
                                 time = "13:45"
                               ),
                               messageItem(
                                 from = "Support",
                                 message = "The new server is ready.",
                                 icon = icon("life-ring"),
                                 time = "2014-12-01"
                               )),
                  dropdownMenuOutput("messageMenu"),
                  dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
                               notificationItem(
                                 text = "5 new users today",
                                 icon("users")
                               ),
                               notificationItem(
                                 text = "12 items delivered",
                                 icon("truck"),
                                 status = "success"
                               ),
                               notificationItem(
                                 text = "Server load at 86%",
                                 icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"),
                                 status = "warning"
                               )
                  )             
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("dashboard")),
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("th"))
    )),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # First tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
              h2("Graphes de suivi"),
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "Graphiques", status = "primary", 
                    plotOutput("plot1", height = 250),
                    plotOutput("plot2", height = 250)
                ),

                box(title= "Informations", status = "info",
                    "Texte descriptif", br(), "blablabla",
                    sliderInput("slider", "Number of observations:", 1, 100, 50),
                    sliderInput("slider2", "Curseur 2:", 1, 200, 25),
                    textInput("text", "Commentaire :")
                ),
                box(title = "Commentaires éventuels", status="success",
                    solidHeader = TRUE,
                    collapsible = TRUE,
                    "Commentaire :",
                    textOutput("text")
                )  
              )
      ),
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
              h2("Widgets tab*** content")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { 
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)
  output$text <- renderText({
    print(input$text)
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    data <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider)]
    hist(data)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    data2 <- histdata[seq_len(input$slider2)]
    hist(data2)
  })
  output$messageMenu <- renderMenu({
    req(messageData, cancelOutput = TRUE)
    msgs <- apply(messageData, 1, function(row) {
      messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["message"]])
    })
    dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, I replaced my messageData with this one, but both seem to produce the right kind of dataframe. Anyway, I got the same error :/

Comment: odd, inputting that line in you code works correctly for me. In you last coded block you have some brackets in the wrong place, See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my code! But I still get the same error... ?

Comment: I have tried to copy paste the code you said you run successfully... and obtained the same error again, the one I copy pasted in my question. I really don't understand why ! How is it the same code gives you a result and gives me an error ?

Comment: I don't know. All i can suggest is upgrading to the newest versions or R, shiny and shinydashboard.

Comment: I reinstalled R a couple of times and rebooted it, and it finally works ! Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the following rows:

```
messageData<-data.frame(from = character(), message = character())
```

and

```
  output$messageMenu <- renderMenu({
    msgs <- apply(messageData, 1, function(row) {
      messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["message"]])
      dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs) 
    }) 
  })
```

You are trying to select something that does not exist. So you should populate meesageData with some Data and change a line of your code by moving it down as follows:

```
output$messageMenu <- renderMenu({
        msgs <- apply(messageData, 1, function(row) {
          messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["message"]])

        })
        dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
      })
```

Comment: Lespied and you gave me the same advice, which I followed, correcting my code as you both advised, thank you both for that ! But I still got the closing window and the same error message...